# Multiple linear regressions according to first column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have `pandas.DataFrame` like:

```
    A    D    V
0  329    0  138
1  329   42  137
2  329   72  141
3  329  106  141
4  329  135  138
5  800    0  150
6  800   30  160
......
```

Now I would like, for each name in `'A'`, I would like to use corresponding numbers to do linear regression.

For example, for `'329'`,I'd like to use `['0', '42', '72', '106', '135']` and `['138', '137', '141', '141', '138']` for linear regression.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` you can process each name separately:

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

def interp(group):
    return list(np.polyfit(group['D'].values, group['V'].values, 1))

# used as
df.groupby('A').apply(interp)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""        A    D    V
    329    0  138
    329   42  137
    329   72  141
    329  106  141
    329  135  138
    800    0  150
    800   30  160"""))

print(df.groupby('A').apply(interp))
```

**Results:**

```
A
329    [0.0122277757944, 138.131827919]
800             [0.333333333333, 150.0]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. But my result keep saying: TypeError: must be str, not float. I don't see why there's any float here?

Comment: Is that with my data or yours?  try `print(df.dtypes)`